# Getting wrong result when using bigint in sql query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sqldatatypes, type-conversion

I have passed below AmountDue in query but am getting wrong result. AmountDue data type is Float.

```
AmountDue: 2412880.28
AmountDue: 561.06
```

My query:

```
select CONVERT(varchar,(select convert(bigint,AmountDue*100)))
from dbo.tblBidResults
```

I am getting below results which is wrong:

```
241288027
56105
```

Correct Result:

```
241288028
56106
```

Comment: What datatype is `AmountDue`?

Comment: AmountDue datatype is Float

Answer (score 1):

try converting to numeric instead of bigint:

```
DECLARE @temp float
set @temp = 2412880.28
SELECT CONVERT(varchar,(CONVERT(numeric(27,0),@temp*100)))
```

There is a [good post](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/29/sql-server-difference-and-explanation-among-decimal-float-and-numeric/) that goes over the reason for this here.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @temp float
set @temp = 2412880.28
select convert(varchar,convert(decimal(9,0),@temp*100))
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/13389)**